# ARM template storage account not found while creating Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template which creates a Storage Account, App Service Plan, Application Insights and a Function App. In the `dependsOn` section of the Function App, I configured it to be depending on the other three resources. But when I deploy the template, it fails with the following error:

*Status Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/dummystorage' under resource group 'dummy-rg' was not found.*

I see that the Storage Account, ASP and App Insights are being created first, followed by the Function App. So it seems the dependency is being honored. It's almost like the Storage Account provisioning is not completely finished when the Function App is being created. As you can see in the template below, the Function App resource uses the `listKeys` to get the Storage Account keys as part of the provisioning.

Does anybody have any idea how I can prevent this from happening? I've read everything in the docs regarding dependencies, and I believe this should just work.

One remark is that the storage account is being deployed based on a condition. I can't imagine it has something to do with my issue, but I just wanted to mention it.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "functionAppName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "appServicePlanName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "appInsightsName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "deployStorage": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": true
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "utcDateTime": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[utcNow()]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "storageAccountDeploymentName": "[concat('storageDeploy-', parameters('utcDateTime'))]",
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
                "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('storageAccountDeploymentName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "powershell"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                            "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageAccountName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                            "value": "[concat(toLower(parameters('functionAppName')), '813b')]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
                    "powerShellVersion": "[variables('powerShellVersion')]"
                },
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
            // snip
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
            // snip
        },
        {
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountDeploymentName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
            "condition": "[parameters('deployStorage')]",
            "properties": {
                "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
                    "scope": "outer"
                },
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            // snip
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're running into this: https://bmoore-msft.blog/2020/07/26/resource-not-found-dependson-is-not-working/

TLDR;
listKeys is called in a separate job in the deployment engine and gets called early if that resource (i.e. your storage) is not in the same deployment.

1. you don't need to nest your storageAccount deployment, doesn't hurt but doesn't help.  If your storageAccount deployment is unconditional, then it will help because ARM will wait before running listKeys.
2. if you need the condition, the only fix is to nest the function app deployment and set a dependency on the conditional storageAccount (the dependency need not be conditional ARM will handle that).  You need to set the evaluation scope to "inner" on that nested deployment.

That help?

Comment: I've read your blogpost. And indeed, this is exactly what I'm running into. This certainly helps to create a workaround. Thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your dependsOn for Storage looks like this:

```
"dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
            "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', variables('storageAccountDeploymentName'))]"
```

Whereas my despendsOn for Storage Account and Blob Container looks like this... could that be the reason it's not working? I have never used **Microsoft.Resources/deployments** (FYI my ARM Template deployment is working)

```
"dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers', variables('StorageAccountName'), 'default', variables('BlobContainerName2'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('StorageAccountName'))]"
```

Comment: When I set the `dependsOn` like your example the deployment fails with the following message: `'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/dummystorage' is not defined in the template`. This is probably a result of deploying the storage account by means of a nested template. The reason I use nested template is that I want to be able to use a condition to deploy a new storage account, or use an existing one. I don't know of another way to be able to use a condition, without using a nested template.

Comment: Hmmm out of curiosity, why do you need conditional? If you redeploy the Storage Account and it already exists, there should be no effect, unless you change something post deployment, or if the Storage account has a dynamically set name based on Timestamp or something. Outside of that, you could drop the conditional and deploy the Storage Account each time. If it exists already no change, if it doesn't exist then it's created. If that's acceptable I can update my answer. But I'm sure it is not preferred work around

Comment: The condition was added to have the ability to use an already existing storage account (deployed outside of the template) for the Function App. But the more I think about it, that scenario doesn't make much sense. It would be better to always use a dedicated storage account for the Function App. I'm going to drop the nested template approach.Thanks Trent for thinking along!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. I will update my answer with the alternative. If you could please mark as accepted answer/upvote that would be appreciated. It's terrible not being able to comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatively:

**You could drop the conditional and deploy the Storage Account each time. If it exists no change, if it doesn't exist then it's created.**

The only caveat to this is if you change something on the storage account post-deployment or if the Storage account has a dynamically set name based on Timestamp or GUID etc.

I realize this is a work around, but it should solve your problem barring the caveat above.

Comment: Redeploying the same storage account each time is not the issue. The idempotency of ARM ensures that nothing happens when the template doesn't change. My point was that I sometimes need to use a different, already existing, storage account. Different in the sense that it's deployed outside of the template, perhaps even in another Resource Group. But I agree with you, I'm letting this go and just always deploy a dedicated storage account for the Function App. Thanks again.